# Best approximation of a mixture of multinomials

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution, mixture-distribution

I have a $k-$components mixture of multinomial distributions, with the following distribution:

$$
M_k(i) = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\pi_j p_j(i)
$$
and I am considering a second mixture $M_l$ with $l<k$ components:
$$
M_l(i) = \sum_{j=1}^{l}\tilde{\pi}_j \tilde{p}_j(i)
$$
From experimental simulations, I see that if the covariance of $M_l$ is similar to the covariance of $M_k$ then $M_l$ is a good approximation of $M_k$, but I would like to have a theorem, or a theoretical result that explicitly states this.

Is this true? There exist any reference relating the distance between mixtures to the distance between their covariances?